# python: representing square grid that wraps on itself (cylinder)

Tags: python, oop

I am modeling something that occurs on a square grid that wraps on itself (i.e., if you walk up past the highest point, you end up at the lowest point, like a cylinder; if you walk to the right, you just hit the boundary). I need to keep track of the location of various agents, the amount of resources at different points, and calculate the direction that agents will be moving in based on certain rules.

What's the best way to model this?

Should I make a class that represents points, which has methods to return neighboring points in each direction? If so, I would probably need to make it hashable so that I can use it as keys for the dictionary that contains the full grid (I assume such grid should be a dictionary?)

Or should I make a class that describes the whole grid and not expose individual points as independent objects?

Or should I just use regular (x, y) tuples and have methods elsewhere that allow to look up neighbors?

A lot of what I'll need to model is not yet clearly defined. Furthermore, I expect the geometry of the surface might possibly change one day (e.g., it could wrap on itself in both directions).

EDIT: One additional question: should I attach the information about the quantity of resources to each Point instance; or should I have a separate class that contains a map of resources indexed by Point?

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like something you'd use modulus for, regardless of how you represent the map.

Comment: Indexing a list with `a[i%len(a)]` will produce the _wraparound_.

Comment: regarding your edit, see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a hashable `Point` class without too much work, subclass tuple and add your own neighbor methods.

```
class Point(tuple):
    def r_neighbor(self):
        return Point((self[0] + 1, self[1]))
    def l_neighbor(self): 
        [...]

x = Point((10, 11))
print x
print x.r_neighbor()
```

The tuple constructor wants an iterable, hence the double-parens in `Point((10, 11))`; if you want to avoid that, you can always override `__new__` (overriding `__init__` is pointless because tuples are immutable):

```
def __new__(self, x, y):
    return super(Point, self).__new__(self, (x, y))
```

This might also be the place to apply modular arithmetic -- though that will really depend on what you are doing:

```
def __new__(self, x, y, gridsize=100):
    return super(Point, self).__new__(self, (x % gridsize, y % gridsize))
```

or to enable arbitrary dimension grids, and go back to using tuples in `__new__`:

```
def __new__(self, tup, gridsize=100):
    return super(Point, self).__new__(self, (x % gridsize for x in tup))
```

Regarding your question about resources: since `Point` is an immutable class, it's a poor place to store information about resources that might change. A defaultdict would be handy; you wouldn't have to initialize it.

```
from collections import defaultdict

grid = defaultdict(list)
p = Point((10, 13))
grid[(10, 13)] = [2, 3, 4]
print grid[p]                  # prints [2, 3, 4]
print grid[p.r_neighbor]       # no KeyError; prints []
```

If you want more flexibility, you could use a dict instead of a list in defaultdict; but `defaultdict(defaultdict)` won't work; you have to create a new defaultdict factory function.

```
def intdict():
    return defaultdict(int)

grid = defaultdict(intdict)
```

or more concisely

```
grid = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```

then

```
p = Point((10, 13))
grid[(10, 13)]["coins"] = 50
print grid[p]["coins"]              # prints 50
print grid[p.r_neighbor]["coins"]   # prints 0; again, no KeyError
```

Comment: Thanks, that's better than defining `__hash__` method.

Comment: Thank you for the additional comment re: storing additional resources. Isn't `Point` mutable itself, except for its `tuple` part? In other words, if I add a new instance variable to Point, wouldn't it be fully changeable with no subtle complications?

Comment: Briefly, because `Point` subclasses from `tuple`, `Point` _must_ be immutable. Less briefly, immutable types set their attributes in their `__new__` function. Once that's done, they cannot be changed, even by a subclass. So because `Point` creates an instance using tuple's `__new__` function (accessed in this case via `super`), the result is an immutable `Point`. The benefit of immutability is that it makes hashing easier & more consistent. If `Point` were mutable, it's possible that the location of `Point` could change, but the hash wouldn't, so `Point` would hash to the same place in `grid`.

Comment: As an addendum, if you wanted to have a mutable `resource` class, you could include `Point` as an attribute of that class. There are even ways to make `Point` read only, so that available resources can change but the location is locked to the instance.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to keep track of the location
>   of various agents, the amount of
>   resources at different points, and
>   calculate the direction that agents
>   will be moving in based on certain
>   rules.

Sounds like a graph to to me, though I try to see a graph in every problem. All the operations you mentioned (move around, store resources, find out where to move to) are very common on graphs. You would also be able to easily change the topology, from a cylinder to a torus or in any other way.

The only issue is that it takes more space than other representations.

On the plus side you can use a [graph library](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) to create the graph and probably even some graph algorithms to calculate where agents go.

Comment: Thank you that's a great suggestion. In this particular case, I can't use it because I need the concept of line-of-sight (which is much easier to define if I keep x,y coordinates), but I will use it in other situations.